# Change the connection string of a bound data set during runtime

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to change the connection string of a bound dataset during runtime?

I have created an application in my laptop, and the server host of my connection is localhost, but when I deploy it in another computer, I wanted my application to a database that resides in another server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose to store the connection string in the Settings file, it is possible. You'll have to override the getter for the connection string. See [this page](http://www.csharpbydesign.com/2008/01/overriding-dataset-settings-co.html) for a full explanation in C#. You should be able to take the same concept and port it to VB.